# Refresh the main screen in ax dynamics 2009

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

How can I refresh the main window using code? I have made a form which makes some changes to the main window. I want to refresh/reload the main window when these changes are made so that they are visible immediately without the user having to refresh the screen manually.

I'm working in Dynamics ax 2009

EDIT: I found out that the changes are also made visible when I reload/change the current module or company. So if there's a way to do that, it's fine too.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe it is possible to refresh the menus or the primary window. The only way I have found to do so is have the user restart their client.